# Combining a function in existing code

Tags: jquery, facebook, api

I am making a "webapp" where you can click on different artists, and it generates an artist page. I display an image, bio,.. I get all this info from a radio api.
Now I also can get "facebook_url" which contains the facebook url, this made me want to display all the album covers from his/her facebook page. Here I am stuck.

I have this working code:  (#albums is a basic div)

```
    function doFacebookRequest(){
    $.ajax({
        url: oSingle.artist.facebook_url+"/albums",     
        dataType: "jsonp",
        success: function(json){
            console.log(json);
            $("#albums").empty();
            for(index in json.data) {
                var album = json.data[index];
                var img = $("<img/>")
                    .attr("src", "http://graph.facebook.com/" + album.id + "/picture");
                var a = $("<a/>")
                    .attr("href", album.link)
                    .append(img)
                    .appendTo("#albums");
            }   
        }
    });
}
```

Now I want to place it in a div tag that I append to my main content (like this:)

```
                    $("<div/>")
                    .html(doFacebookRequest)
                    .appendTo(contentdiv);
```

The above is obviously wrong, but I have no idea how to correctly make the function in an appending piece of code.

I need to do this because all my code is in that appending format, for example:

```
                    $("<img/>")
                    .addClass("artistimg")
                    .attr("src", "http://images.q-music.be/" + oSingle.artist.photo)
                    .appendTo(contentdiv);

                $("<h1/>")
                    .text(oSingle.artist.name)
                    .appendTo(contentdiv);
```

etc..

Comment: the html that you are adding to the `div` is what is returned in that request, yes?

Answer (score 0):

jQuery's html function can accept a function like you have in your question, but will set the html to what is returned by the function. In your example, the function does not return anything, therefore nothing will be set in your DIV.

Also, the AJAX call is asynchronous so your current pattern will not work effectively because it would have to block execution and wait for Facebook to respond. This is generally a bad idea that your pattern reinforces. Something using callback methods would be much more effective for that.

That said, you should be able to get what you want by forcing the AJAX request to be synchronous, and returning HTML. To do that, set async to false in the ajax call. That will cause the request to execute synchronously. Next, create an arbitrary DIV before the ajax function call. Add the content to the arbitrary DIV. After the ajax function call completes, return the HTML content of the arbitrary DIV.

Something like the following should give you what you want:

```
function doFacebookRequest(){
    var content = $('<div/>');
    $.ajax({
        url: oSingle.artist.facebook_url+"/albums",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        async: false,
        success: function(json){
            console.log(json);
            for(index in json.data) {
                var album = json.data[index];
                var img = $("<img/>")
                    .attr("src", "http://graph.facebook.com/" + album.id + "/picture");
                var a = $("<a/>")
                    .attr("href", album.link)
                    .append(img);
                content.append(a);
            }   
        }
    });
    return content.html();
}
```